# networkx: multiple figure with consistent node placement

Tags: python, networking, matplotlib, graphviz, beamer

I am using networkx to draw multiple figure of the same graph, as I add more and more edges to the graph. The figures are included in consecutive slides in a slideshow.

I want the nodes in each figure to be displayed in exactly the same position in each figure. Unfortunately, although I am using the same positioning data for each plot, the figure is scaled down a little bit each time I add an edge close to the side of the figure.

This is what I mean:
[image]

This is the code that I'm using at the moment:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

num_nodes = 100
num_edges = range(10, 80, 5)
file_name = "evolution1"

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(num_nodes, num_edges[-1])
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog="neato")


for (i, ne) in enumerate(num_edges):
    plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))

    nx.draw(G,
            pos,
            with_labels=False,
            node_size=15,
            node_color="black",
            edgelist=G.edges()[:ne])

    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig(file_name + "-%s.pdf" %i, format="pdf",
                transparent=True)
```

What I want is that the nodes stay in the same stop on each consecutive slide, which would be much more visually pleasing. Could anyone help me out?

P.S. in case this is relevant, the way that I put the figures in the slideshow (which is made with LaTeX/Beamer), is with

```
\begin{center}
  \multiinclude[<+>][start=0,format=pdf]{pics/evolution1}
\end{center}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself, for anyone interested. The solution is to call plt.xlim and plt.ylim. I added the following:

```
maxx = max([coor[0] for coor in pos.values()])
maxy = max([coor[1] for coor in pos.values()])
```

and then, just before saving the figure to a file, add

```
plt.xlim([-10, maxx + 10])
plt.ylim([-10, maxy + 10])
```

This resolves the issue.